# make:***[install-confdir] Error 1

Tags: software-installation

I am new to Linux. I am getting this error while trying to install QEMU emulator on my Ubuntu VM using these steps.

1. Clone the IAP 6.828 QEMU git repository `git clone https://github.com/geofft/qemu.git -b 6.828-1.7.0`
2. Configure the source code: `./configure --disable-kvm --prefix=./hsrf7/home/Qe --target-list="i386-softmmu x86_64-softmmu"`
3. Run `sudo make && make install`

Error after 3rd step:

```
install -d -m 0755 "/usr/local/share/qemu"
install -d -m 0755 "/usr/local/etc/qemu"
install: cannot change permissions of `/usr/local/etc/qemu': No such file or directory
make: *** [install-confdir] Error 1
```

Comment: Run `sudo make && sudo make install`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, now as an answer

Run `sudo make && sudo make install`

Because you don't have permissions to copy to /usr/local

Comment: `make && sudo make install` will do.

Comment: I never `make`d qemu, but +1 for your comment

Comment: You never need `sudo` for `make` and you almost always need it for `make install`.

Comment: I doubt that. Only `make` executes the first target. If there is a command that needs sudo rights you have to use `sudo make`

Comment: No compilation commands need sudo rights.

Comment: I agree. But I don't see the Makefile and therefor I don't know what is being executed. You can say, in most cases the first target in a Makefile only compiles, so `make` is enough. But i have seen enough Makefiles where that is untrue.